# "Today summary" widget in notification centre displays strange behaviour

Tags: macos, notifications, widgets

I have upgraded from El Capitan to Sierra a couple of weeks ago. Today, I have been experimenting with widgets in Notification Centre and came across this puzzling issue. I am not sure whether it is a bug or intended behaviour hence I decided to ask a question and confirm.

This is what my Notification Centre looks now

[image]

As you can see, "Today" has no frame or border around it. However, when I try to edit widgets, it appears

[image]

Prior to me removing and adding "Today" widget, it *had* border/frame both, when displayed and when being edited.

Is this a bug in Sierra or intended behaviour?

Comment: That's intended.

Comment: Image embeds above are broken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The today widget has no widget frame or title, except when in edit mode where the remove button is shown. This is standard behaviour since the today widget can be removed and added, but cannot be rearranged.

Comment: Isn't it inconsistent (UI-wise) in comparison to "Tomorrow" widget?

Answer (score 0):

That’s normal behavior. When you edit widgets, the borders appear to show the “stop sign” allowing you to remove (and drag, if applicable) the widget.

I’ve never seen the borders around the **Today** widget in *viewing* mode.